# trying the same code after error in php

Tags: php, try-catch

It can be a noob question. Is it ok to try the same code after giving error due to the server overload. Or what is the best solution to avoid this?
For example, the following is the part of curl request:

```
     $xml = simplexml_load_string($sData);
     $result = ($xml->result);
     $description = ($xml->description);
```

Rarely above script gives the following two E_NOTICE in my log file:

```
E_NOTICE: Undefined variable: result in ...
E_NOTICE: Undefined variable: description in ...
```

I think it is because the remote server is busy that time. But if I try the curl request after a minute it works fine.
What is the best way to avoid this situation? Can I try the script by catching the thrown error? But I have not used try catch blocks. Please assist me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try looping until you get what you need (Or a maximum is reached). For example:

```
$done = false;
  $tries = 0;  
  do {
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($sData);

  if ( !empty($xml->result) && !empty($xml->description) ) {
    $done = true;
  } else {
    $tries++;
    sleep( 1 );
} while ( !$done && $tries < 10 );
$result = $xml->result;
$description = $xml->description;
```

I don't know whether this is the best solution, but it should work. (You might try some other checks instead of `empty`, change the sleeping time and the retry count in order to adjust to your needs, but the general idea stands.

Comment: Thanks @Muc. What if other requests come from my other customers while the server is waiting for sending the previous request. What happens in that case?Can my server handle it? And do you think it is because it can't load $sData? But there is no info on my error log file about $xml or $sData.

Comment: If some other customers were making the same request, it would depend on your server's capabilities to respond (Hardware, config, etc...). Perhaps that is what is happenning here, the server can't handle so many requests, so it drops some... You might want to look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php in order to check for xml errors.

Comment: I do not think it drops because of my customers. It might be because of 3rd party server that I am requesting. As for libxml error, that is a good point.I will have a look at. One more question. Do you think the problems is simplexml can't load the string in the curl request? or do I have to loop the whole curl request or just the part that you mentioned above. Currently I am testing only the part you provided me above. I have slightly changed. Let me see what happens. But it takes some time since it happens rarely. I will post the result :).